# Error adding item to Azure Storage Queue from Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage-queues

Have a (so far) very simple Azure Function in Python. Trying to use Azure Queues for the first time. Modeling off of [the tutorial here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-output?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python). When I try to run this I get the following error:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function:
> Functions.applyNewSurvey123. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
> Exception: TypeError: unable to encode outgoing TypedData: unsupported
> type "<class
> 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.generic.GenericBinding'>" for Python
> type "list" Stack:   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions
> Core
> Tools\workers\python\3.9/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py",
> line 425, in _handle__invocation_request
> param_binding = bindings.to_outgoing_param_binding(   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core
> Tools\workers\python\3.9/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\bindings\meta.py",
> line 160, in to_outgoing_param_binding
> datum = get_datum(binding, obj, pytype)   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core
> Tools\workers\python\3.9/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\bindings\meta.py",
> line 108, in get_datum
> raise TypeError( .

My code:

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest, 
         msg: func.Out[str]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    jsonString = req.get_json()

    try:
        msg.set(jsonString)
        return func.HttpResponse("HTTP triggered successfully.", status_code=200)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error: {e}")
        return func.HttpResponse("NOPE", status_code=500)
```

I've got an Azure Storage Queue set up and function.json seems to be set up correctly. If I set msg to just some plain text, it gives the same error. If I set a logging.error message after msg.set(), I do see the message. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question and add the whole error traceback message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below and I have followed [Micrsoft-Documnet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-queue/azure.storage.queue.queueclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-queue-queueclient-send-message) and below is the python code which worked for me:

```
from azure.storage.queue import QueueClient
qc = QueueClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rithwikstore;AccountKey=voop0PvnAUcSHWrWd6WLmNkHpA64RWNPol9OWTTXI5DbtEE/y8M113JlJATzn24LkzeNveTeOHS3+AStQIsUZg==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net", queue_name="rithwik")
msg = "Hello Rithwik"
qc.send_message(msg)
```

[image]

Here you should give your queue name (queue_name) and connection string (conn_str) of Storage account.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks much! That change worked as expected. :)